# Find closing HTML tag in Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublimetext

I have a very long and very nested HTML document, where I need to quickly find the closing tag. How can I do this?

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/489879/edit-both-opening-and-closing-html-tag

Ctrl + Shift + ' // with emmet plugin

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try Emmet plug-in command *Go To Matching Pair*:

http://docs.emmet.io/actions/go-to-pair/

Shortcut (Mac): <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Shortcut (PC): <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions

Comment: Cool, thanks. I am actually using Emmet so that is ideal. The shortcut is: **Shift + Control + T**.

Comment: for Windows user, the shortcut at the time of writing is Control + Alt + J

Comment: Thanks! Control + Alt + J works in Linux as well (tested under Linux Mint 14, Sublime Text 3)

Comment: @AllanRuin Ruin For me on Windows, with Emmet active in ST2, it just works to jump to the closing tag from starting tag, not the other way round.

Comment: Emmet plugin works great. You dont HAVE to use the keyboard shortcut, just open you Palette in sublime (Shift + Command + P) and start typing 'matching pair')

Answer (score 138):

There is a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Windows and Linux users, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Mac users) to select the whole block within the currently selected tag.

For example, if you pressed this while your text cursor was within the outer `div` tag in the code below, all the `div`s with class `selected` would be selected.

```
<div class='current_tag_block'>
  <div class='selected'></div>
  <div class='selected'></div>
  <div class='selected'></div>
  <div class='selected'></div>
</div>
```

As @frazer-kirkman mentioned in a comments you can also move your cursor to the start or to the end of the selected block by pressing either <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> button on a keyboard depending on your cursor's position

Comment: To select the parent tag as well, just use the shortcut again and it expands the selection!

Comment: it doesn't exactly answer the question, but the answer then becomes trivial.  To find the closing tag you need to look at the end of the selection, or push the right arrow key.

Comment: Where is this documented? Is this combination part of some plugin? It is impossible to find this on the following: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html

Comment: You sir, deserve an upvote +1. It's also possible on Visual Studio!: `Shift` + `Alt` + `=` to expand and `Shift` + `Alt` + `-` to deselect

Answer (score 13):

It's built in from Sublime Editor 2 at least. Just press the following and it balances the HTML-tag

Shortcut (Mac):  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>

Shortcut (Windows):  <kbd>Control</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked on Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10,
Ctrl + Shift + ' with the Emmet Sublime Text 3 plugin works great and was the only working solution for me.
Ctrl + Shift + T re-opens the last closed item and to my knowledge of Sublime, has done so since early builds of ST3 or late builds of ST2.

Answer (score 4):

Under the "Goto" menu, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is Jump to Matching Bracket. Works for parentheses as well.

Comment: Works for brackets, works for parenthesis, but not work for html tags.

Comment: −1. Doesn't answer the question, which is about HTML tags.

Comment: It is only finding matching parentheses.  How do I set this feature to also look for `{ } [] <>` ?

Answer (score 4):

As said before, `Control`/`Command` + `Shift` + `A` gives you basic support for tag matching. Press it again to extend the match to the parent element. Press arrow left/right to jump to the start/end tag.

Anyway, there is no built-in highlighting of matching tags. Emmet is a popular plugin but it's overkill for this purpose and can get in the way if you don't want Emmet-like editing. [Bracket Highlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) seems to be a better choice for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you may want to try another approach with folding enabled.

In both ST2 and ST3, if you enable folding in User settings:

```
{
    ...(previous item)
    "fold_buttons": true,
    ...(next item, thus the comma)
}
```

You can see the triangle folding button at the left side of the line where the start tag is. Click it to expand/fold. If you want to copy, fold and copy, you get all block.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this for me is that I type `</` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and if it doesn't close the correct tag, I know that I've got a dangling open tag somewhere, I just don't know WHERE that open tag is in this 6000 line HTML file.

Comment: Try some formatting plugin? Maybe codelint or something? Some online ones, maybe

Answer (score -1):

Just press CTRL+f and write </ and click on button "Find All". so all the closing tags will be show selected and also count on far bottom left corner.

Comment: what about false positives like attribute strings like `data-str="/>"`?