# How to jump into next Tag using sublime 3 short cut?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Good day,

I have a bunch of `<li></li>` on my html file. Is there any keyboard shortcut so I can go to next LI without clicking or pressing key many time. for example i have 3 li element, if I am done typing on my first (li) `<li>done</li`>, then how can i go to next pair of

```
<li></li>
```

[image]

" without pressing the -> key or down key many times to be able to type on next `<li>` pair? Thank you for your tips :)

Its just kind of tiring if done often. specially on tables and list items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find closing HTML tag in Sublime Text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814182/find-closing-html-tag-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Im not looking for its ending tag, Ive added an image on my question above, hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In Emmet Documentation is called "Go to Edit Point"
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd>

To go to previous edit point
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd>

Try this page - it's got mini demo videos too : )
http://docs.emmet.io/